# How do I display a surface without tracking with steamvr(openvr)?

Tags: openvr

When there is no tracking, the head display will automatically show the gray blue, unable to display the need for the screen. The application we develop needs to run without a tracking, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Steam/config/steamvr.vrsettings  under the steamvr section add:
"forceFadeOnBadTracking" : false